# Why can't I find my repo after Git Clone into SSH?

Tags: python, django, git, ssh, git-clone

I am a beginning programmer going through this [Test-Driven-Development tutorial](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch08.html#_adjusting_the_database_location). I've reached the chapter where I need to spin up a server and register some domain names that I can then use with my Django project and I've been able to do everything up until now.

This step in the tutorial has me `git clone` my repo into the server, switch to the repo directory, and then run `python3 manage.py runserver` to get the expected "django is not installed on the server" error.

The problem is that while it appears my repo has been successfully cloned, I cannot see the directory. Here is the error I am seeing:

```
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~$ git clone https://github.com/user/superlists.git \~/sites/$SITENAME/source
Cloning into '~/sites/staging.user.com/source'...
remote: Counting objects: 530, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (363/363), done.
remote: Total 530 (delta 153), reused 521 (delta 148), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (530/530), 699.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (153/153), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~$ cd ~/sites/$SITENAME/source
-su: cd: /home/user/sites/staging.user.com/source: No such file or directory
```

I had assumed that since Git successfully cloned into `~/sites/$SITENAME/source` that the directory would have been automatically created. But when I went looking I couldn't find it:

```
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~$ cd sites
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~/sites$ ls
staging.user.com
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~/sites$ cd staging.user.com
user@ip-172-31-41-131:~/sites/staging.user.com$ ls
database  static  virtualenv
```

This is my first posted question on SO. I have been here MANY times before and always look to see if anyone else has the same problem/question as me, but I could not find anyone else who has encountered this - although I'll admit I'm not sure the best way to ask it.

Full disclaimer: The tutorial strongly suggests using Django v1.8, however I have been using v1.9 and have been able to search for any weird errors until now, but I can't see how that would matter since Django isn't even installed on the server. If I am wrong then I look forward to being enlightened.

Comment: `cd \~/sites/$SITENAME/source`. You should add \ before ~ or ~ is interpreted as /home/username/ instead. But try not to use ~ as part of a new path name. You could also use `cd '~/sites/$SITENAME/source'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are escaping the `~` in the destination path, so it is being treated literally instead of expanding to your home directory (you will now have a directory called `~` the root of your filesystem!).

This should work:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/user/superlists.git ~/sites/$SITENAME/source
```

(note, no backslash before the `~`). git should also tell you the expanded path that it is cloning into:

```
Cloning into '/home/user/sites/staging.user.com/source'...
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. The "\" was in the tutorial example I'm using and I, being the newbie that I am, took it literally. Sure enough, in the root of my filesystem I had two directories named `~`.